# Spring donwload binary file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to write a controller to download binary file.

Source code follows:

```
  public @ResponseBody byte[] getOpenedEventsInPdf(HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource(SRC_FILE);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + FILE_NAME);
    response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.addHeader("Expires", "0");

    headers.setContentLength(pdfFile.contentLength());

    byte[] toRet = toByteArray(new DataInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(SRC_FILE).toURI()))));
    byte[] bte = { (byte) 128, 65, (byte) 129, 65, (byte) 130 };
    System.out.println(toRet[0] & 0xFF);
    System.out.println(toRet[0]);
    System.out.println(toRet.length);
//        return toRet ;
    return bte;
}
```

But the problem is if I return bte, i am getting exactly 5 bytes
If I return toRet, i get 509 bytes. But the source FILE_NAME contains 256 bytes, starting from 0-255.

I am guessing following line has something to do.

```
byte[] toRet = toByteArray(new DataInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(SRC_FILE).toURI()))));
```

Because values above 127 got modified. What am I missing?

-- requested code from comment --

```
private byte[] listToByteArray(List<byte[]> input) {
    if (input == null || input.size() == 0) {
        return new byte[] {};
    }
    byte[] toRet = {};
    for (byte[] b : input) {
        toRet = ArrayUtils.addAll(toRet, b);
    }
    return toRet;
}

private byte[] toByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    List<byte[]> byteArrayList = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    while (true) {
        byte[] buff = new byte[READ_BYTE_LENGTH];
        int r = is.read(buff);
        if (r == -1) {
            break;
        } else if (r == READ_BYTE_LENGTH) {
            byteArrayList.add(buff);
        } else {
            byteArrayList.add(Arrays.copyOf(buff, r));
        }
    }
    return listToByteArray(byteArrayList);
}
```

If you wander why I did this madness when guava or apache common lang offer all the available? It's because I am going nuts over this

Comment: Can you post the code of `toByteArray()`

Comment: @Vasan I have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized, my InputStream or reading mechanism has nothing to do with the data corruption. Maven is modifying the PDF files and my test binary files to be UTF-8. I am looking for that solution. Thank you all who took interest in the question.

Comment: I have solved the problem with the following code adding in build under project of pom.xml

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
      <nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>
      <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
     </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

Answer (score 0):

I think your reading of bytes is way more complicated than it needs to be, and probably is to blame for the problem. If you're using java 9, you should just do

```
private byte[] toByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    return is.readAllBytes();
}
```

and if you're not, use something like:

```
private byte[] toByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[16384];

    while ((int nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
       buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
    }

    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering
No, I am using Java 8, and the reason I found has nothing to do the way I am readying this. I do not need to write byte reading as I have mentioned in my question. I wrote this out of frustration and to investigate in details. 
But the reason I found is interesting. Maven making copy of the resource files and both my PDF file and random binary files are being corrupted in the directory itself.

Comment: @Popeye I think you've encountered maven filtering issue. I propose to close the question, as nowhere in the question you've even mentioned maven.